# Why ng-model is not defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have three  angular-ui-bootstrap typehead in a form

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="fieldname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected" typeahead="name as name.name for name in members | filter:{name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="fieldhname" class="col-md-3 control-label">House name</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected1" typeahead="house_name as house_name.house_name for house_name in family | filter:{house_name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />

   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="" class="col-md-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_family_id'); ?></label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.customSelected2" typeahead="fm as fm.family_reg_no for fm in family | filter:{family_reg_no:$viewValue}" class="form-control" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<input type="button" class="finish btn-success btn" ng-click="search(newItem)" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

the search button calls the function,

```
$scope.search = function(item) {
    item['id']=item.customSelected.id;
    item['family_id']=item.customSelected1.id;
    item['family_id']=item.customSelected2.id;
     delete data.customSelected;




     FamilyMemSearch.get(item, function (response) { // success

            $scope.tableData = response.data; // store result to variable

            }, function (error) { // ajax loading error
                Data.errorMsg(); // display error notification
            });

      };
```

but it shows an error customSelected1,customSelected2 is undefined.

Comment: Can you share a jsFiddle or plunk to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Perhaps because they do not have the properties of "id"?

Comment: i gave id.but again it shows error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ngModel` automatically creates properties only **after the value changes first time**. If you don't initialize the `item.customSelected1`, `item.customSelected2` and click search right after page loads, the values will be `undefined`.

Try initializing your `item.customSelected1` and `item.customSelected2`

```
app.controller("yourController",function($scope){
    $scope.newItem= {};
    $scope.newItem.customSelected1 = {};
    $scope.newItem.customSelected2 = {};
});
```

Comment: @Nisham Mahsin: my mistake, it should be `newItem` instead of `item`. I updated the answer