# Pushing string to Array in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi guys I'm trying to learn Angular to make Ionic apps and I'm following a tutorial on Angular,  the thing is that not all angular statements work for Ionic. Im trying to push a name and a city from input's to an array (don't need to save them.

These are my input fields:

```
<p>What is your first name? </p>
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
<p>What city do you live in?</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
<button ng-click="addCustomer()">Become a customer</button>
```

This is how all names and cities are displayed:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name"> {{cust.name + " from " + cust.city}} </li>
</ul>
```

This is the controller:

```
demoApp.controller('simpleController', function ($scope){
    $scope.customers =  [
        { name: 'jasper', city: 'Amsterdam' },
        { name:'Dave',city:'phoenix'} ,
        { name:'Gina', city:'Amsterdam' },
        { name: 'Philip', city:'Otterloo'}
        ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
      $scope.customers.push(
          {
              name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
    };
});
```

I'm following a tutorial and I've searched on stack and google but really can't find what I am doing wrong, I hope someone can help me out.

P.S. I'm kind of new on stack so if I did something wrong (stack rules wise) please don't hesitate to point it out to me.

**EDIT**: someone asked for full app.js code

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ionic']);

demoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    home: {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'simpleController'
    }
  }
})

$stateProvider.state('help', {
  url: '/help',
  views: {
    help: {
      templateUrl: 'help.html',
        controller: 'simpleController'

    }
  }
})
});

demoApp.controller('simpleController', function ($scope){
    $scope.customers =  [
        { name: 'jasper', city: 'Amsterdam' },
        { name:'Dave',city:'phoenix'} ,
        { name:'Gina', city:'Amsterdam' },
        { name: 'Philip', city:'Otterloo'}
        ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function() {
      $scope.customers.push(
          {
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: try doing a console.log and see if you can debug it in an emulator

Comment: Thanks got this error in the console: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Scope.$scope.addCustomer" in my app.js

Comment: Have not yet found a solution though

Comment: Your code looks 100% right you make some changes at other pages may be

Comment: can you show full code of app.js

Comment: Done, thanks for your responses guys.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj0L4bgd/ your code works.

Comment: Oke well I guess it's a problem with  Ionic Lab of some sorts, anyway that explains why I could not find a solution. Thanks a bunch people I'll try jsfiddle-ing it next time before I post.

Comment: Why the downvote? :s

Comment: Honestly I'm still not convinced that what I did was correct, the jsfiddle was just for angular, where in fact i think the problem lies in the fact that I'm using Ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and no my code was not correct. 
The solution was to put:

```
    $scope.newCustomer= {};
```

Right under the controller, the issue was that newCustomer was undefined.

Thank you all for helping me.

Happy coding!

EDIT: Credits to Khanh TO found his answer on this stack pos: [Why ng-model is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431610/why-ng-model-is-not-defined) .